# How to make the color of a TextView like this image?

Tags: java, android, textview

I want to set the color of a textview like this image, It has a vertical red color line and entire textview is like pink or reddish color.

[image]

Comment: What have your tried so far?

Comment: I know most of the common attributes of a textView but for red part ( vertical line ) have no clue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a linear layout with orientation horizontal and put a view inside it.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".FirstFragment">

    <LinearLayout
        android:background="@color/teal_200"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/button_first"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
        <View
            android:layout_width="5dp"
            android:background="@color/cardview_dark_background"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textview_first"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingStart="5dp"
            android:text="@string/hello_first_fragment"
            android:background="@drawable/side_line"
             />

    </LinearLayout>


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_first"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/next"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/textview_first" /></androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Just change the colors and you are good to go.
The output looks like this...[image]

Comment: Also please accept the answer if it works for you :)

Comment: Accepted your answer. Appreciate your information

Answer (score 1):

You can use layer list. No need more views

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape
            android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/teal_700"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:start="5dp">
        <shape
            android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/teal_200"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

In your TextView

```
android:background="@drawable/your_layer_list"
```